# Is it illegal to answer duplicates?

Tags: discussion

I wrote an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33615111/javascript-how-to-get-the-month-name-of-the-current-date-without-setting-an-arr/) yesterday. Today I woke up and opened the stack exchange app to find out its missing. When I logged in through my laptop I found out it was deleted by a moderator and the question was flagged duplicate. I found it weird cause I am new here and was just sharing knowledge.

Comment: "I found it weird cause I am new here" - Just a heads up, SO is absolutely not a bad place to hang around, but it doesn't care about you being new. It has a help center full of topics and a searchable meta full of existing knowledge that you can study so you don't have to use the argument "I'm new" for anything. Be "SO did my due diligence" before you are "SO readytohelp".

Comment: SO ready to plagiarize

Answer (score 9):

Did you write an answer, or did you copy (a miniscule part of) a comprehensive answer (and later added proper attribution)?

And as the answer exists on the same site, what value did you add over doing the right thing and simply voting (or, since you are below 3K still, flagging) to close as a duplicate?

And if it had been a new answer adding to SO's knowlegebase, why did you add it to the duplicate even though you obviously knew a good duplicate-master?

Answer (score 2):

Illegal? No. Strongly discouraged? Not really. Depending on how obvious the dupe should have been to someone with your searching abilities, other users may get annoyed at you, but unless you make a habit of never bothering to dig up dupes and simply answering with the same trivial answers, that annoyance won't be very substantial. (Please do not do that. We don't need people to *answer* the same questions over and over.)

I don't know for sure why your answer was *deleted*, but I'd guess it's just because "Extracting month from date in JavaScript" is frankly the sort of question you'd expect to find at least a hundred dupes of.

A solid, helpful answer on a question that turns out to be a dupe will seldom be deleted.